# How to property save a UIImage from imagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage

How do you property save an image from imagePickerController? I'm able to display the image into a UIImageView just fine but when I try to do anything else with the image, the image remains nil. You can see how I'm saving the image below.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
self.image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; //self.image is a UIImage property
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
self.image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

You should dismiss image picker after you save images, because `info` is object retained by image picker (and info is there till image picker not dismissed), correct approach:

```
self.image =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now you can do with image everything that you want.